# Find the same String in different Strings

Tags: java, string

i want to extract these Strings (XXXXX,GGGGG,PPPPP) from this Strings:

- COPY  XXXXX,PFX='PPPPP';
- COPY  XXXXX,PFX='PPPPP',GRUPPE='GGGGGG';
- COPY  XXXXX;
- COPY  XXXXX,'PPPPP';
- COPY 'XXXXX','PPPPP','GGGGG';
- COPY 'XXXXX','PPPPP',SUPPR='YES';
- COPY XXXXX,PPPPP,GGGGG;

My problem is, that all these strings are different and i can't extract them. For every singel string i can do a regex, but not for all in one method.

- xxxx can be e.g. TWT000
- PPPP can be e.g. TWS000
- GGGG can be e.g. TWSOOO

Any chance of getting all string types in one method to extract XXXX,PPPP,GGGG?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem, what are the rules here?

Comment: Is it always one "word" between a space and a comma, after the initial `COPY`? With optional ticks?

Comment: Try to find a pattern to select the strings: you have "COPY " and then your strings separated by commas

Comment: The eclipse tag isn't needed. It's purely a language issue

Comment: Skip first field, then filter the rest by some pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split every string by space, then split by coma(,). For example(`COPY XXXXX,PFX='PPPPP',GRUPPE='GGGGGG';`):
first step:

COPY

XXXXX,PFX='PPPPP',GRUPPE='GGGGGG';

next step:

XXXXX

PFX='PPPPP'

GRUPPE='GGGGGG';

each line is a cell in array after splitting. Use some ifs to make regexp check or something if you must, for example in `SUPPR='YES';` you don't want to parse YES.

Now extract everything inside '' quotations.
You have successfully extract your data.

Answer (score 0):

use batch files and cmd commands you will find alot of helpful functions there

```
@echo off
findstr /m /c:%1 %2
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo found
)
```

%1 is the string you are looking for 
%2 is the text file you are searching into

and you can output the result into another file with ">"